# Blender to Xcode through baking textures

Tags: ios, swift, 3d, textures, 3d-modelling

We are facing an issue where our Blender model looks significantly different when converted from .dae to .scn format for use in Xcode. We have followed the necessary steps for texture baking and file conversion, but the visual disparity persists.

We have checked texture baking settings and material assignments, and the conversion process appears error-free. How can we effectively troubleshoot this problem? What factors could be causing the noticeable differences between the Blender model and the converted model in Xcode?

Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Our 3d model in blender:

[image]

Our 3d model in xcode:

[image]

The settings of the simplebake blender extension that we are using to bake our 3d model:

[image]
[image]